# Range between numbers and if else statement

Tags: python, list, numpy, range, iterable

I'm slowly learning Python on my own so here is a problem I've been running into.

Trying to step through each number up to the last number and depending on the range it steps into then a calculation will be made.

```
NUM = []
for b in range(1,8760):
  if 3000 < b < 7000:
    NUM=500
  else:
    NUM=300
writer.writerow([NUM])
```

> TypeError: 'int' object not iterable

I also tried this below and it runs but only prints out one number for the whole list instead of choosing between the two number options...

```
NUM = []
for b in range(1,8760):
  NUM = numpy.where((b > 3000) & (b < 7000), 500, 300)
writer.writerow([NUM])
```

Comment: Can you paste the **exact** error and the line it refers to?

Comment: `NUM=300` - Do you understand that `NUM` is no longer a list at this point?

Comment: You are welcome! If it helped, please upvote my answer and mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean this instead?

```
NUM = []
for b in range(1,8760):
  if 3000 < b < 7000:
    NUM.append(500)
  else:
    NUM.append(300)
writer.writerow(NUM)
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks.  Now I have to figure out how to print the list vertically in a csv file.  Thanks again

Comment: You are welcome! If it helped, please upvote my answer and mark it as correct :)

Comment: To make it one line: `writer.writerow([map( lambda x: 500 if 3000<x<7000 else 300, range(1, 8760))])`

Comment: @ccf: Ugh. `map` with `lambda` is terrible, just go for the `list` comprehension at that point. Only reason to prefer `map` is if an existing Python built-in function can do the work directly, otherwise, list comprehension is faster, and no more verbose (and behavior is consistent across Py2/Py3): `[[500 if 3000<x<7000 else 300 for x in range(1, 8760)]]`

Comment: @ShadowRanger: I agree with you. List comprehension is faster in this case. So the answer is: `writer.writerow([500 if 3000<x<7000 else 300 for x in range(1, 8760)])`

Answer (score 1):

You're changing NUM inside your loop to a number either 500 or 300.

I think what you're looking for is to append to your list

Try:

```
NUM.append(500)
```

or

```
NUM.append(500)
```

This will add to NUM and you will end up with a list of 500s and 300s depending on your if condition.

You can see how this structure works [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) in the python documentation.